# ffill col[c] based on col[a]==Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe [pixel, total_time], i want to:

- Make a new column "total_time_one", which takes total_time of pixel 1 and projects it

```
 pixel  total_time  total_time_one
     1     218.835         218.835 #projected times of pixel 1 onto all valyues
     1     218.835         218.835
     1     218.835         218.835
     2     219.878         218.835
     2     219.878         218.835
     2     219.878         218.835
     3     220.911         218.835
     3     220.911         218.835
     3     220.911         218.835
     1     230.189         230.189 #value changes cause pixel 1 shows up again
     1     230.189         230.189
     1     230.189         230.189
     2     231.441         230.189
     2     231.441         230.189
     2     231.441         230.189
```

I have acheved the above dataframe with :

```py
uniqueone = df.query("pixel==1").total_time.unique()
mask = df["total_time"].isin(uniqueone)
df["total_time_one"] = (df[mask]["total_time"])#putting it here isn't working: .fillna(method='ffill')
df["total_time_one"] = df["total_time_one"].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Howver the code is quite long and repeats itself, **is there a function better suited? or a better solution?**

Also i do not undestand why if i put:

```py
df["total_time_one"] = (df[mask]["total_time"].fillna(method='ffill')
```

It doens't work, and i have to put an extra line:

```py
df["total_time_one"] = df["total_time_one"].fillna(method='ffill')
```

to make it work

Comment: Are you saying your code is four lines and is quite long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where` to `NaN` the values that aren't `'pixel'==1` and then `ffill`. This technically forward fills the last value of each group, but your values are static within each group of pixels.

```
df['total_time_one'] = df['total_time'].where(df.pixel.eq(1)).ffill()
```

---

```
    pixel  total_time  total_time_one
0       1     218.835         218.835
1       1     218.835         218.835
2       1     218.835         218.835
3       2     219.878         218.835
4       2     219.878         218.835
5       2     219.878         218.835
6       3     220.911         218.835
7       3     220.911         218.835
8       3     220.911         218.835
9       1     230.189         230.189
10      1     230.189         230.189
11      1     230.189         230.189
12      2     231.441         230.189
13      2     231.441         230.189
14      2     231.441         230.189
```

---

If you wanted to use the `first` value within each group (as opposed to the last), or say take the average and then `ffill` you can use `groupby` + `transform`. You label successive groups of `1`s using the cumsum of a `!=` comparison.

```
df['total_time_one'] =  (df['total_time'].where(df.pixel.eq(1))
                            .groupby(df.pixel.ne(1).cumsum())
                            .transform('first')  
                            .ffill())
```